# how to change UISwitch from 0/1 to on/off

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Might be my question is too easy, but I don't know how to resolve my problem. I created UISwitch in code:

```
  UISwitch *soundSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, 10, 150, 50)] autorelease];
```

It show switch with 1/0 values. I want to show On/Off. If I put UISwitch in designer mode it shows On/Off. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I figured out, if the current local is english then it will show "on/off" If its another language it will show I/0.

Comment: Why it shows different text if I create UISwitch from code and from designer?

Comment: UISwitch behavior differs from the iOS version and device, but you can't customize it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](http://www.catamount.com/blog/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/), will help you i think..

Comment: Is it impossible to create UISwitch with ON/OFF text without creating custom control? Why it shows different text if I create UISwitch from code and from designer?

Comment: Of course its not impossible, you can look at your subviews of UISwitch and find labels after this, set your labels how you want.

Comment: Can anybody answer why it shows different text if I create UISwitch from code and from designer?